# TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required in the django-channels

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, django-channels, uvicorn

*Requirements*

- Python 3.8
- asgiref                           3.2.0
- channels                          2.4.0
- channels-redis                    2.4.2
- Django                            3.0.9,
- gunicorn                          20.1.0
- redis                             3.5.3
- uvicorn                           0.11.5
- websockets                        8.1

I run channels as `gunicorn -w 5 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-level debug -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker config.asgi:application`.
Also I have `nginx` as proxy-server.

*Logs*
[image]

```py
class TokenAuthMiddleware:
 
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner
 
    def __call__(self, scope):
        return TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance(scope, self)
 
 
class TokenAuthMiddlewareInstance:
    def __init__(self, scope, middleware):
        self.middleware = middleware
        self.scope = dict(scope)
        self.inner = self.middleware.inner
 
    async def __call__(self, receive, send):
        try:
            token_key = (dict((x.split("=") for x in self.scope["query_string"].decode().split("&")))).get(
                "token", None
            )
        except ValueError:
            token_key = None
        if token_key is None:
            self.scope["user"] = AnonymousUser()
        else:
            token_data = await get_token_data(token_key)
            self.scope["user"] = await get_user(token_data["user_id"])
 
        inner = self.inner(self.scope)
        return await inner(receive, send)
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you figure it out?